# Get value by key from json array

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a few json arrays

```
[{"key":"country","value":"aaa"},{"key":"region","value":"a"},{"key":"city","value":"a1"}]
[{"key":"city","value":"b"},{"key":"street","value":"1"}]
```

I need to extract city and street value into different columns.

Using `get_json_object($"address", "$[2].value").as("city")` to get element by it's number doesn't work because arrays can miss some fields.

Instead I decided to turn this array into a map of key -> value pairs, but have trouble doing it. So far I only managed to get an array of arrays.

```
val schema = ArrayType(StructType(Array(
      StructField("key", StringType),
      StructField("value", StringType)
    )))

from_json($"address", schema)
```

Returns

```
[[country, aaa],[region, a],[city, a1]]
[[city, b],[street, 1]]
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
val schema = ArrayType(MapType(StringType, StringType))
```

Fails with

```
cannot resolve 'jsontostructs(`address`)' due to data type mismatch: Input schema array<map<string,string>> must be a struct or an array of structs.;;
```

I'm using spark 2.2

Comment: can you please show the input DF and excepted DF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using UDF we can handle this easily. In the below code I have created a map using a UDF. I hope this will suffice the need

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df1 = spark.read.format("text").load("file path")
val schema = ArrayType(StructType(Array(
      StructField("key", StringType),
      StructField("value", StringType)
    )))

val arrayToMap = udf[Map[String, String], Seq[Row]] {
  array => array.map { case Row(key: String, value: String) => (key, value) }.toMap
}
val dfJSON = df1.withColumn("jsonData",from_json(col("value"),schema))
    .select("jsonData").withColumn("address", arrayToMap(col("jsonData")))
    .withColumn("city", when(col("address.city").isNotNull, col("address.city")).otherwise(lit(""))).withColumn("street",  when(col("address.street").isNotNull, col("address.street")).otherwise(lit("")))
dfJSON.printSchema()
dfJSON.show(false)
```